# Cannot resolve library in gradle with mavenCentral

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am building a android application with gradle in Android Studio, and i have a dependency `jackson-databind`, but i get a error `can't resolve xxx`, even i use my private repo and i sure that library is there.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And i get a error.
[image]

Comment: please post both entire bulid.gradle files

Comment: Hi, user1434702 its work in my project hence try to clean your project and then try again

Answer (score 1):

I update my gradle to 3.2 and it work well.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may just need to sync your build.gradle file, click the "Sync Now" like in this image here: https://postimg.org/image/v0yro39cl/